# Seguir link com Enter baseado em entrada de usuário

Tags: html, redirecionamento, redirecionamento-de-url

Com a ajuda da comunidade, criei um arquivo para redirecionar um usuário que digitou seu login para uma página na web que recebe o usuário dessa forma:

https://site.com.br/usuario=LOGIN&empresa

O problema é que geralmente o usuário aperta Enter ao digitar o texto, então tentei adequar o código para que ao apertar essa tecla fosse redirecionado, mas aparentemente o link não está recebendo a variável.

Poderiam me auxiliar a, ao apertar Enter ou clicar em Entrar depois de inserir seu login, o usuário seja direcionado?

Segue o meu código:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />

<title>Redirecionamento</title>
<div class="page-margin"></div>
<br>
<br>
<div align="center" class="welcome-form-div">
  <div class="welcome-form">
    <div class="html-logo">
      <i class="icon-comments-alt"></i> Insira os números do seu
      <br><b>login</b> <i>ou</i> <b>CPF</b> e clique em Entrar
      <br>
      <br>
    </div>

    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" size="20">
    <input type="button" id="BotaoLogin" value="Entrar" onClick="redirecionar()">
</div>


<script language="javascript">

var username = document.getElementById("username");

username.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    redirecionar(e);
  }
});

function redirecionar() {
  if (username != "") {
    window.location = "https://site.com.br/usuario"+username+"&empresa";
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function redirecionar() {
  var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
  if (username != "") {
    window.location = "https://site.com.br/usuario"+username+"&empresa";
  }
}
```

Falto capturar o valor do elemento.

Comment: Perfeito! Deu certo! Obrigado.